# What is the easiest way to put an index to a repeater control in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

I want an ASP:NET WebForms Repeater control to put an index next to each of its output rows automatically. How can I do that?

Example:

```
   Name
1  John
2  Jack
3  Joe
```

Comment: That's so not clear. What have you tried so far? What's your code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Container.ItemIndex %></td>
            <!-- or maybe -->
            <td><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Maybe use a `<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>`, to get a 1-based number.

Comment: Cheers, I've put that in. I assume it'll work :) My own use case uses the zero-based index.

Comment: I used `DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex")`

Comment: how to force repeater generate new itemtemplate on specific index @Rawling